# Exporting image collection keeping the image dates as band name in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to save 6 years daily MODIS data in a single image with multi bands.I specifically want the dates as band names.I have been tring to run this script but the page crashes or becomes unresponsive. I want the export a single multi-band image with names such as this: 2021_01_01_LST_Day_1km..

This is my script.

```
// use a geometry to select the study area
var geom = ee.FeatureCollection('users/payeldastidar/STATE_BUFF_WGS')
var output_name = 'LST_2002_2006'
var crs = 'EPSG:4326'


//print(geom)

// filter image collection to time period of interest 
var startDate = '2002-01-01'
var stopDate  = '2006-01-01'

// resulting image collection - same set of images as in the python GEE atmospheric correction code
var LST_MOD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
    .filterBounds(geom)
    .filterDate(startDate,stopDate)
    
    //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 1))
    .sort('system:time_start');


var LST_Assam = LST_MOD.select('LST_Day_1km')



// convert image collection to multi-band image
var LST_Assam_band = ee.ImageCollection(LST_Assam).iterate(function(img, all){
  return ee.Image(all).addBands(img)}, ee.Image().select())
LST_Assam_band = ee.Image(LST_Assam_band).multiply(0.02).float()
print(LST_Assam_band,'LST_Assam_band')

// get band names for each collection
var LST_Assam_band_names = ee.Image(LST_Assam_band).bandNames() // s1 or s2_vi1 or pl_vi1
print(LST_Assam_band_names, 'LST_Assam_band_names')

// get a list of image dates
var date_list = ee.ImageCollection(LST_Assam).toList(LST_Assam_band_names.length()) 
var date_list2 = date_list.map(function(img) {
  return ee.Image(img).get('system:index')
  //return ee.Image(img).date()
})
print(date_list, 'date_list')
print(date_list2, 'date_list2')

var bnames = ee.List([])
for (var i = 0; i < date_list2.length().getInfo(); i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < LST_Assam.length().getInfo(); j++) {
    var bname = ee.String(LST_Assam.get(j)).cat(ee.String(date_list2.get(i)))
    var bnames = ee.List(bnames).add(bname)
  } 
}

var LST_Assam_export = ee.Image(LST_Assam_band).rename(date_list2)
print(LST_Assam_export, 'LST_Assam_export')
 // Export image to drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: LST_Assam_t, 
  description: output_name, 
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  crs: crs, 
  region: geom
});
```

Comment: Please share the error message or at least indicate where it fails "in the middle"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The page becomes unresponsive and crashes. I want something like this: "2002_01_01_LST_Day_1km" ......."2022_01_01_LST_Day_1km"as the name of the bands after exporting it.

Answer (score 0):

In general if you have to make a for loop in Earth Engine it is worth to consider an alternative. There is a build-in function available for earth engine: `.toBands()`

Depending on what it is you exactly want this is probably your best option. see for example: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-tobands

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b8ab7b0a98b87c6e53ebb944d9b0fe35

Also, for future questions it is helpfull if you share a working example and give some detail on your aim.

Comment: I tried this and downloaded the data. However I wanted the dates as the name of each band. When I opened the data, it showed the names as this:                                               [961] "LST_2002_2022.961"  "LST_2002_2022.962"  "LST_2002_2022.963"  "LST_2002_2022.964"  "LST_2002_2022.965"  "LST_2002_2022.966" 
 [967] "LST_2002_2022.967"  "LST_2002_2022.968"  "LST_2002_2022.969"  "LST_2002_2022.970"  "LST_2002_2022.971"  "LST_2002_2022.972"

Comment: When I export the 'imageCollection' object I create in the script, the output of the example script is an 10-band image with the following names: 2002_01_01_LST_Day_1km, 2002_01_02_LST_Day_1km, 2002_01_03_LST_Day_1km, 2002_01_04_LST_Day_1km, 2002_01_05_LST_Day_1km etc.. Which is the expected outcome if I understand you correctly. So you'll have to specify what you are doing more clearly for me to be able to help you any further.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested. Here is the link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b74f5e43ae8e11ba07a6d960b317f379

Comment: your assets are not shared so I can't reproduce it sorry

Comment: I changed the setting to "anyone can read". I think you can have access to it now.Sorry i am new to this

Comment: I don't have the same problem. When the intermediate output 'imageCollection' is printed to the console the bandnames are exactly as I specified above: 2002_01_01_LST_Day_1km etc. which is the date format YYYY_mm_dd_LST_Day_1km. Also when I open the image in QGIS bands are named accordingly.

Comment: okk.Thank you.I found a way to append the band names in R.